# MySQL, PHP, Ajax to filter result set?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm new to MySQL & would like to "filter" a result set by region.  I have previously asked a similar question but I don't know if I'm meant to create a new question or continue that one, sorry if I've got this wrong.

I've looked at the http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_database & think it would be ideal, but I'm not sure how to get it working, or how I can get it to "update" the results.

Ideally I suppose a drop down box below the region  would look tidy - but, I'm not having any success - I really am totally limited to my understanding, can anyone help? (thank you to previous folks who helped with the first part too!!)

This is all I have so far, (to give an idea of what I'd like to filter).

Many thanks, scotia - below is the regionbox.php file

...

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
function selectRegion(str)
{
var xmlhttp;    
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("region").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("region").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","regionbox.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<P>
<table class="dbTable">
    <tr>
    <tr><th>Commodity</th> <th><form action="regionbox.php"> 
<select name="region" onchange="selectRegion(this.value)">
<option value="">Select Region</option>
<option value="E. Midlands">E. Midlands</option>
<option value="Gtr. London">Gtr. London</option>
<option value="North East">North East</option>
<option value="North West">North West</option>
<option value="Scotland">Scotland</option>
<option value="South East">South East</option>
<option value="South West">South West</option>
<option value="W. Midlands">W. Midlands</option>
<option value="Wales">Wales</option>
</select>
</form></th> <th>Member</th> <th>Size</th> <th>Price</th> <th>Date Posted</th>
    </tr>

<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', '', '');

$db_selected = mysql_select_db('palegall_newTrader', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('cant find newTrader' . mysql_error());
}

$region = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['region']);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `sell` WHERE `commodity` = 'paper' ORDER BY `price`") 
       or die( mysql_error() ); 

    echo '<table class="dbTable">';

     while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))  
    { 

      echo '<tr><td>'.$row['commodity'].'</td> <td>'.$row['region'].'</td> <td>'.
                      $row['member'].'</td> <td>'.$row['size'].'</td> <td>'.
                      $row['price'].'</td> <td>'.$row['posted'].'</td> </tr>'; 
    }
    echo "</table>"; 
    ?> 
</body></html>
```

I've stripped out bits. I hope this is OK.

Comment: good call on making this a new question. We need to see the relevant code in `regionbox.php` in order to answer your question, please remove the link in order to not have people hack your site.

Comment: Oh, thank you I really appreciate it...where should I add the regionbox.php code? (sorry!)

Comment: Copy paste **the relevant portions of it**  in your question., then select the code and press `CTRL+K` to make it look like code.

Comment: What do you want to do? Only show the elements that match the Dropdown values? Or "refetch" data from your database each time you pick a filter?

Comment: Sorry @Antonio - I had mmissed your post - yes, Id like to "refetch" Im osrry for my question not being clear!!!

Comment: @scotia consider performance on making this kind of refetchs and also user experience. What kind of content should you expect to see when you access the table the first time? Is really needed to refetch data from the database each time you select something? The answer I gave you just "modifies" the DOM so no extra calls are made and will have better performance than refetching. However if you really need it, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @Antonio thank you, I need two tables, buy & sell to show all data at first, then refectch when the filter is chosen.  This wont ever be a live site :) I have to collect my father from hospital so wont be back online until later tonight.  Many thanks again.

Comment: An option is to use [fancybox](http://fancybox.net) with jQuery, that is a great tool for beginners needing AJAX page queries, but it is a lightbox app that may not be appropriate for your site. It also calls a page via AJAX instead of refreshing content in this usage, example, I have a page called with a number of variables for specification of the data I want returned (e.g. task.php?taskid=task&userid=user&anotervar=something), this means I don't need to worry about the entire JS/AJAX call, I can query mySQL via standard PHP using the variables in the URL and it is requested/returned by AJAX

Comment: @Ryan thank you for your comment too, Im not able to use additional resources for this sadly, I really need to do it the way Im trying to :) Many thanks!

Comment: Hi. While updating your code is good I just want to warn you that if you edit your post too many times it will automatically become Community Wiki.

Comment: Thank you Belinda I didnt realise that!  What is the best method of updating? Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

Change this code

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `sell` WHERE `commodity`='Paper' 
                      ORDER BY `price`") 
   or die( mysql_error() ); 
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);  
do 
{ 
  echo'<table class="dbTable">'; 
  echo '<tr><td>'.$row['commodity'].'</td> <td>'.$row['region'].'</td> <td>'.
                  $row['member'].'</td> <td>'.$row['size'].'</td> <td>'.
                  $row['price'].'</td> <td>'.$row['posted'].'</td> </tr>'; 
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)); 
  echo "</table>"; ?>
```

Into:

```
$region = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['region_Name']);
//For debugging: 
echo $region
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sell WHERE commodity = 'paper' 
                      AND region = '$region' ORDER BY price") 
   or die( mysql_error() ); 

echo '<table class="dbTable">';

//echo the rows in a while loop
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))  
{ 

  echo '<tr><td>'.$row['commodity'].'</td> <td>'.$row['region'].'</td> <td>'.
                  $row['member'].'</td> <td>'.$row['size'].'</td> <td>'.
                  $row['price'].'</td> <td>'.$row['posted'].'</td> </tr>'; 
}
echo "</table>"; 
?>
```

Comment: ...Ive had a few error messages but Im certain Im just doing it wrong! - so am just working through them, I really appreciate your help...back soon!

Comment: ...sorry - I cant see where Imm going wrong, the error message seems to refer to the echo at the end? Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO, expecting T_WHILE in /home/palegall/public_html/Reassessment/regionbox.php on line 108  

By putting the WHILE back at the end I can get the headers to show up with the drop down, but no initial data shows - sorry to be so stupid.

Comment: @scotia, left a `do` that doesn't belong in there, sorry 'bout that.

Comment: By removing the AND variable the data will show as before, but  no functionality of the drop down?

Comment: @Scotia, the `AND region = '$region'` limits the result to only those regions. I don't know the layout and fieldnames in your database so you need to tweak the query to match your database, also you need to make sure the values in your dropdownlist are identical to the regions use in your database.

Comment: ...thank you - that makes sense & Im going to check through every name I have! I cant see any other reason for it not working, many thanks again & Ill no doubt be back to annoy you :)

Comment: ...Im really sorry - still no luck.  My db is called newTrader & has seven tables including `sell` which I want to use for this - `sell` has seven columns, all lower case - one being region.  Ive gone back through & checked the function names & column, drop down names & option names, its iteresting that no data shows when I include the AND region, but if I leave it out I get the original result set...suggests its a naming thing but I cant find it!

Answer (score 3):

Ok, since you're not answering I'll put a little script which I often use and have a neat effect.

It needs jQuery to be present in your website

```
$('select').change(function(){
var region  = $(this).val();
    $("tr").each(function () {
        if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(region, "i")) < 0) {
            $(this).hide();
        } else {
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
});
```

You may see this working here http://jsfiddle.net/6psNF/1/

You should adapt your table code so, for example table could have an ID and the row with the code could have a class. Tiny code with tiny example:

```
<table id="trader">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>Random</td>
    <td class="region">E. Midlands</td>
    <td>Member</td>
    <td>Size</td>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td>Date</td>
    <td>Posted</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

So, the code I wrote could end like

```
$('select').change(function(){
var region  = $(this).val();
    $("#trader tr").each(function () {
        if ($(this).text().find(".region").search(new RegExp(region, "i")) < 0) {
            $(this).hide();
        } else {
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
});
```

Increasing performance in pages with a lot of content or super big tables!

Comment: Dreadfully sorry - I had missed posts abovve & was trying to make sure I hadnt mixed up names etc - I really do appreciate everyone's help - scotia

Comment: Oh don't worry @scotia I just wanted to write an useful reply :-)

Comment: I think I understand the purpose of the above code, but Im not sure about the jquery & am worried if I try something too different from what Im working with just now I'll confuse myself further - sorry guys you ended up with the plonker.  I need all the data to show first, then have the dropdown filter the results.  :)

Comment: That's what this answer does! First fetch all the content and then filter it. Try it here http://jsfiddle.net/6psNF/1/ and you'll see that. I ended with a jquery solution because it needs few lines of code and have a great performance and also because your question was tagged as jquery!

Comment: Oh, I wonder how that happened?  I didnt tag it as such since I kno nothing about them? Apologies. I had a look at the link you suggested so will go back & now try to make it for my tables & try it out.  Many thanks again ot everyone trying to help me with this.

Comment: Comment if you have more questions regarding this. I'll try to help you.

Comment: Id really appreciate the support, (& from everyone so far) thank you - is it possible for you to help me with what I have so far?

Comment: Hello, thank you again to all those above, - I am still struggling with this.  Should I create a new question or continue here - many thanks.

Comment: Depending on what are you trying to accomplish. As far as I think, this code I put works flawlessly with just loading jquery in your page which is painless!